# Error while showing feeds in blogger

Tags: rss, feeds

I am trying to show my feeds on a blogger blog. The feed url is [this](http://www.apptec.net/?feed=rss2) but blogger says invalid feed url. The url opens fine on my browser.Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Blogger wants this format: `http://feeds.feedburner.com/Apptec?format=xml`